# Adiabatic Quantum Computer e intermediate Hamiltonian evolves the state within the manifold

Tags: mathematics, annealing, adiabatic-model

The Adiabatic Quantum Computer is implemented by slowly increasing the parameter s from 0 to 1 in the intermediate Hamiltonian $[\hat{H}(s) = \hat{H}_{input} + (1-s)\hat{H}_{init} + s\hat{H}_{circuit}]$

How to show that this process evolves the state within the manifold spanned by $\{ |\alpha(0)\rangle|0_c\rangle,|\alpha(1)\rangle|1_c\rangle...|\alpha(L)\rangle|L_c\rangle$. In other words I meant to say how to show that $\hat{H}(s)$ does not map any state in this manifold to a state outside this manifold.

where $|\alpha(L)\rangle$ is is the data qubit state after applying the $l_{th}$ logic gate ,i.e $|\alpha(l)\rangle = \hat{U}_l...\hat{U}_1|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$

$\hat{H}_{input} = \sum_{i=1}^n|1_i\rangle\langle1_i|\otimes|0_c\rangle\langle0_c|$

$\hat{H}_{init} = \sum_{j=1}^L|j_c\rangle\langle j_c|$

$\hat{H}_{circuit} =  \sum_{l=1}^L \hat{I} \otimes |(l-1)_c\rangle\langle(l-1)_c| - \hat{U}_l \otimes |l_c\rangle\langle(l-1)_c| - \hat{U}_l^\dagger \otimes |(l-1)_c\rangle\langle l_c|+  \hat{I} \otimes |l_c\rangle\langle l_c|$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very particular application of Adiabatic Quantum Computing so I think it's worth briefly mentioning some context.

Roughly speaking, one wants to show that given a quantum circuit defined as a sequence of unitary gates $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_L$ it is possible to define a version of the quantum adiabatic algorithm that reproduces (a state with a large overlap with) the output state of the circuit: $\lvert \alpha(L) \rangle = U_L \cdots U_1 \lvert 0 \rangle^{\otimes n}$. Here we are assuming the circuit is initialized in the state $\lvert 0 \rangle^{\otimes n}$ at the beginning of the computation.

The Hamiltonian $H(s)$ that does this is defined over a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_{comp} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{clock}$ that is the tensor product of a "computational" register (which is the same Hilbert space over which the quantum circuit acts) and an auxiliary "clock" register. The standard reference for these constructions is the article [Adiabatic Quantum Computation is Equivalent to Standard Quantum Computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405098).

Now, in answering your question I will assume you've chosen your clock states $\lvert l_c \rangle$ to be orthonormal (as you should have). Following the notation of the reference above, define

$$
\lvert \gamma_l \rangle \equiv \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \lvert l_c \rangle 
$$
Then your question $H(s)\lvert \gamma_l \rangle \in \mathcal{S}_0$ where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}_0 \equiv \operatorname{span}\Big\{ \lvert \gamma_l \rangle \;\Big| \;l=0,1,\ldots,L \Big\}
\end{equation}
boils down to showing that for any choice of $0 \leq s \leq 1$ and $l=0,1,\ldots,L$ the state $ H(s) \lvert \gamma_l \rangle $ can be written as a linear combination of the states $\{\lvert \gamma_l \rangle \mid l=1,0\ldots,L\}$.

Since $H(s)$ is a sum of terms proportional to $H_{input}$, $H_{init}$ and $H_{circuit}$, it is sufficient to show that the states
\begin{equation}
H_{input}\lvert \gamma_l \rangle, \qquad H_{init}\lvert \gamma_l \rangle, \qquad \text{and} \qquad H_{circuit}\lvert \gamma_l \rangle
\end{equation}
are all linear combinations of the $\lvert \gamma_l \rangle$s. This can be done by inspection:

$$
H_{input}\lvert \gamma_l \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert 1_i \rangle \langle 1_i | \alpha(l) \rangle \otimes \lvert 0_c \rangle \langle 0_c | l_c \rangle = \mathbf{0}
$$
because if $l \neq 0$ then $\langle 0_c | l_c \rangle=0$ while for $l=0$ we have $\lvert \alpha(0) \rangle = \lvert 0 \rangle^{\otimes n}$ so all the single-qubit projectors $\lvert 1_i \rangle \langle 1_i \rvert$ will annihilate the state $\lvert \alpha(0) \rangle$. Then
\begin{equation}
H_{init} \lvert \gamma_l \rangle = \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \otimes \sum_{j=1}^L \lvert j_c \rangle \langle j_c | l_c \rangle = \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle  \lvert l_c \rangle
\end{equation}
since here the sum is over all clock states (which are orthonormal) and $\lvert l \rangle$ is one of them. Finally for $H_{circuit}$ you can split the terms
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^L \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \otimes \lvert (k-1)_c \rangle \langle (k-1)_c | l_c \rangle &= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $l=L$}\\ \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \lvert l_c \rangle & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}\\
\sum_{k=1}^L U_l \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \otimes \lvert k_c \rangle \langle (k-1)_c | l_c \rangle &= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $l=L$}\\
\lvert \alpha(l+1) \rangle \lvert (l+1)_c \rangle & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
\sum_{k=1}^L U^{\dagger}_l \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \otimes \lvert (k-1)_c \rangle \langle k_c | l_c \rangle &= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $l=0$}\\
\lvert \alpha(l-1) \rangle \lvert (l-1)_c \rangle & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
\sum_{k=1}^L \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \otimes \lvert k_c \rangle \langle k_c | l_c \rangle &= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $l=0$}\\ \lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \lvert l_c \rangle & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}
so that you have
\begin{equation}
H_{circuit} \lvert \gamma_l \rangle = \begin{cases}
\lvert \alpha(0) \rangle \lvert 0_c \rangle - \lvert \alpha(1) \rangle \lvert 1_c \rangle& \text{if $l=0$}\\
2\lvert \alpha(l) \rangle \lvert l_c \rangle - \lvert \alpha(l+1) \rangle \lvert (l+1)_c \rangle - \lvert \alpha(l-1) \rangle \lvert (l-1)_c \rangle & \text{if $0 < l < L$}\\
\lvert \alpha(L) \rangle \lvert L_c \rangle - \lvert \alpha(L-1) \rangle \lvert (L-1)_c \rangle & \text{if $l=L$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
so in all cases $H_{circuit} \lvert \gamma_l \rangle$ is a linear combination of the $\lvert \gamma_l \rangle$ states. Putting everything together observe that
\begin{equation}
H(s)\lvert \gamma_l \rangle = (1-s)\lvert \gamma_l \rangle + sH_{circuit} \lvert \gamma_l \rangle
\end{equation}
so $H(s)\lvert \gamma_l \rangle \in \mathcal{S}_0$ and this completes the proof.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! We hope to see much more of you, and thank you for your contribution! Not a bad first answer!!

Comment: @user1271772 thanks! I will try my best :)